# PortAudio: how to generate multiple sounds

Tags: c++, multi-channel, tone-generation

I have simple wave generator in PortAudio. I'm creating single sine wave, and then I use a lookup sine to play it. Now I've stucked here. I have no idea how I can add another sine sound. Is it possible to somehow add new channel with another sound?

Here is my code:

soundengine.cpp

```
#include "soundengine.h"
#include <QDebug>

void SoundEngine::run()
{
    PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
    int i;
    double t;
    turnOFF = false;
    isPressed = false;

    static unsigned long n=0;
    for( i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++, n++ )
    {
        t = (double)i/(double)SAMPLE_RATE;
        data.sine[i] = 0.80f * (float) sin( ((double)i/(double)TABLE_SIZE) * M_PI * 2. );
    }
    data.phase = 0;
    data.phase_increment = CalcPhaseIncrement(0);


    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy inicjalizacji strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);

    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); /* default output device */
    if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) qDebug()<<"Błąd: Brak domyślnego urządzenia wyjścia!";

    outputParameters.channelCount = 2;       /* stereo output */
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32; /* 32 bit floating point output */
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              NULL, /* no input */
              &outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff|paDitherOff,      /*paNoFlag we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              patestCallback,
              &data );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy otwieraniu strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);
    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy starcie strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);

    while (turnOFF == false) {
        Pa_Sleep(500);
    }

    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy zatrzymywaniu strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);
    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy zamykaniu strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);
    Pa_Terminate();
}

float SoundEngine::LookupSine( paTestData *data, float phase )
{
    float fIndex = phase*TABLE_SIZE;
    int   index = (int) fIndex;
    float fract = fIndex - index;
    float lo = data->sine[index];
    float hi = data->sine[index+1];
    float val = lo + fract*(hi-lo);
    return val;
}

int SoundEngine::patestCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    paTestData *callData = (paTestData*)userData;
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    float sample;
    unsigned long i;

    (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) inputBuffer;

    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
            sample = LookupSine(callData, callData->phase);
            *out++ = sample;  /* left */
            *out++ = sample;  /* right */

        callData->phase += callData->phase_increment;
        if( callData->phase >= 1.0f ) callData->phase -= 1.0f;
    }

    return paContinue;
}

void SoundEngine::generateSine()
{
    if(isPressed == false)
    {
        data.phase_increment = CalcPhaseIncrement(220.0);
        isPressed = true;
    }


}

void SoundEngine::removeSine()
{
            data.phase_increment = CalcPhaseIncrement(0.0);
            isPressed = false;
}
```

To play sound I use `generateSine()` method. Maybe is there better way to play sound at given frequency, using one method(like `generateSine()` in my example). I would like to play two sounds by using `generateSine()` method twice.

Comment: Simply add the two waveforms together in time domain. Unless you are specifically asking about multi-channel usage in PA, then this is out of the scope.

Comment: but when I'll add another waveform to my actual waveform, and then change my phase_increment - it will change pitch of two waveforms. Some time ago I've done it without interpolation(lookup table), but with every sound there was noise at beginning and ending of sound becouse I didn't know how to fade it. Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: no, adding two tones doesn't change the pitch. You might be running into clipping, however, but you could solve that by scaling each tone with e.g. 0.5 prior to adding.

Comment: I didn't say adding tone change the pitch. Look at my example where I am control pitch by phase_increment. When I will have two waveforms added it will give me one waveform, that's pitch will be still controlled by phase_increment.

Comment: I don't understand that statement. You generate two tones with different phase increments. Then you add these two. That's the way to go.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how to implement that. I've done it for one sine, but have no idea how to apply it for more than one waveform.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of PCM (pulse-coded modulation, i.e. time samples of audio) is that the mathematical sum of two signals sounds like the acoustical superposition.

So, just add your two sines sample-wise.

Comment: huh, a downvote? That's democratically very fine with me, but I'd love to hear why!